# ImportError: No module named 'decouple' using pyenv

Tags: django-rest-framework, pyenv-virtualenv, python-decouple

as I'm using pyenv-virtualenv I have created my Pipfile and I'm trying to run the server with the command *pipenv run python manage.py runserver* but I'm getting the error: **from decouple import config, Csv ImportError: No module named 'decouple'**.

I have installed the module python-decouple and I have written the packages in my pipfile as well. I used the command *pip freeze > requirements.txt*

[pipfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJOVC.png)

When I run the server with the command *python manage.py runserver* I don't get that error. I think that I have to use the command **pipenv run python manage.py runserver** if I'm using pyenv. Any ideas to solve this issue?

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
django = "*"
python-decouple = "*"
psycopg2-binary = "*"
django-cors-headers = "*"
djangorestframework = "*"
drf-base64 = "==2.0"
pillow = "*"
six = "==1.16.0"
django-naomi = "*"
gunicorn = "*"
xhtml2pdf = "*"
drf-yasg = "*"

[scripts]
server          = "python manage.py runserver"
startapp        = "python manage.py startapp"
migrate         = "python manage.py migrate"
makemigrations  = "python manage.py makemigrations"
createsuperuser = "python manage.py createsuperuser"

[dev-packages]


[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```